# Hibernate exception - hibernate.internal.QueryImpl cannot be cast

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to authenticate with a database username. So far the error is:

```
  Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

  Reason: org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl cannot be cast to com.**.**.model.UserEntity
```

The query in the dao class

```
@Repository
public class UserEntityDAOImpl implements UserEntityDAO{


@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public Session getCurrentSession() {
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

    @Override
public UserEntity getUserByName(String username) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
UserEntity userEntity = (UserEntity) 

     sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(


    "select u from UserEntity u where u.username = '' + username + ''");

            return userEntity;
}
```

service

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private UserEntityDAO userEntityDAO;

@Autowired
private Assembler assembler;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UserDetails userDetails = null;

    UserEntity userEntity = userEntityDAO.getUserByName(username);

    if (userEntity == null)

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");

    return assembler.buildUserFromUser(userEntity);


}

    }
```

DB table that holds the user details

```
  /*Table structure for table `user` */
  CREATE TABLE `user` (
 `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
 `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
 `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
 `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "")
@Component
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "active")
private boolean active;

@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
@OneToMany
private Set <Role> roles;

public UserEntity() {

}

   //getters and setters
```

What I would like insight on is why there is a problem with the query, and why the username is not able to be retrieved from the database.

Edit: After changing the query, the login is still not successful. The login page is returned and there is no error message in the output console other than this:

```
   Hibernate: select userentity0_.user_id as user1_1_, userentity0_.active as 

   active1_, userentity0_.name as name1_, userentity0_.password as password1_, 

   userentity0_.username as username1_ from user userentity0_ where 

   userentity0_.username=?


   Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user1_1_1_, roles0_.role_id as role2_2_1_, 


   role1_.role_id as role1_0_0_, role1_.role as role0_0_ from user_role roles0_ inner 

   join role role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.role_id where roles0_.user_id=?


   INFO : com.**.**.controller.ApplicationController - This is the login page {}.
```

Comment: horrible indentation... can you make sure your code looks fine when you are asking questions?

Comment: and, try to isolate the part that is related to the problem.  There is no point pasting the code of service.

Comment: Hi I'm sorry for the haphazard code presentation. I've tried to amend it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to execute the query you created. It should be:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(...).uniqueResult();
```

Also, use a proper bind variable. As it stands your query is bogus with single quotes, I'm not sure if you made a typo pasting it into stackoverflow, but something like this would be much safer:

```
sessionFactory
  .getCurrentSession()
  .createQuery("select u from UserEntity u where u.username = :username")
  .setParameter("username", username)
  .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Yes I omitted to add the.uniqueResult. I've changed the query now, but now when I enter the user details nothing happens except the HQL query showing in the stacktrace. Am I missing something pls?

Comment: the query is NOT showing the stacktrace.  There is an exception thrown to cause stacktrace being displayed.  You should provide the exception information

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. There is no exception information in the output or on the page. The login page is still onscreen , and the HQL select query is shown in the console. I have added this to my first post.

Comment: there is no "stack trace" in the updated message you provided.  They are simply the actual SQL executed.  Have you actually execute those SQL in your DB and make sure record can actually be retrieved?

Comment: Sorry there is no stack trace, no error messages in the console. It's just the select query being executed. I executed a select query SELECT * FROM user
WHERE username='**'  in my DB and it did return the username and the rest of the user details. It's just the login to the homepage which is not working.